# Custom WordPress Plugin critique as to why my echos are outputting in the header of my Page and not the content area

Tags: wordpress

I have attempted random filters and other hook modifiers to try to get my echoed results on the Page content area NOT the header, and I have *failed miserably*. **I am looking for any suggestions or hints as to how post the echoed results to the content area of the Page and not the header area.** To clarify: My results are appearing on the Page I assigned them to BUT they are populating in the header of the page?? Not the main content body area.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'cv_testimonials_list');

function cv_testimonials_list($query) {
    if ($query->is_page('9595') && $query->is_main_query()) {
        gravity_form(1, false, false, false, '', false);
        $args = array (
    'post_type'              => 'testimonial',
    'post_status'            => 'published',
    'pagination'             => true,
    'posts_per_page'         => '10',
    'order'                  => 'DESC',
    'orderby'                => 'date',);

    // The Query
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

                              echo "<p><strong>" . the_content() . "</strong></p>";

                              echo "<p>" . the_title() . "</p>";

                              echo "<p><a target='_blank' href='http://" . get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'testimonials-website-url') . "'>" . get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'testimonials-website-url', true ) . "</a></p>";

                             //print "<pre>";
                                 //print_r($custom_fields);
                             //print "</pre>";  
    endwhile;
    return;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're using functions that echo their values, not return them.  The values are being echoed when they're evaluated, not where they're needed.

Try using [`get_the_content()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content)and [`get_the_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title) instead.

**EDIT**

Sorry, just noticed *where* you're echoing your stuff.  You don't need to run your query in `pre_get_posts`, just modify it, eg

```
$query->set( 'post_type', 'testimonial' );
```

WordPress will then run the query for you in the normal scheme of things.

Not sure what `gravity_form` is doing, but I doubt `pre_get_posts` is the right place for it.  If what you're really trying to do is use that code as your page content,  I'd move all your code out of the hook, into a [custom page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates), and assign page 9595 to that page template.

**EDIT 2**

Create a page template like this in your theme, then in your admin screen, assign it to page 9595 (and delete the code from `pre_get_posts`):

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Testimonial List
 */

$args = array (
    'post_type'              => 'testimonial',
    'post_status'            => 'published',
    'pagination'             => true,
    'posts_per_page'         => '10',
    'order'                  => 'DESC',
    'orderby'                => 'date'
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );


get_header(); ?>
<div id="content" class="widecolumn"><?php

    gravity_form(1, false, false, false, '', false);
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

        echo "<p><strong>" . get_the_content() . "</strong></p>";

        echo "<p>" . get_the_title() . "</p>";

        echo "<p><a target='_blank' href='http://" . get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'testimonials-website-url') . "'>" . get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'testimonials-website-url', true ) . "</a></p>";

    endwhile;


?>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

In this case, you're not trying to change the main WordPress query, you're just not using it - you're using your own query in the template and looping over that.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but I can't see how that would solve the issue.

Comment: Hmm; I'll update my answer with a bit more detail.  But basically, you're outputting your data in a hook that just shouldn't be used for output. `pre_get_posts` should be used to change the query and that's it.  What you're echoing really belongs in a page template